# SSRS - How to see query inside Shared datasets

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report deployed ina a server. I have to see how the report is collecting data. The datasets and datasources are shared in this case. How do i have to check the query in the shared datasets?

I'm able to locate the shared data source and dataset location in report server but have no options to see what is inside that. Please help

Comment: You could download it and add it to a test solution then open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways i can think of achieving this, First is to Edit in report builder from the drop down, the second is to download and then add it to a projects and open it up there.

[image: Capture]